# How many times a digit show up

Tags: c

Please help me. I don't get why the out put is in "occurs" is "30", instead of '3'.. It's as if I'm multiplying the answer with '10', but I'm not.. Maybe the answer to my problem is right in to my code but Can someone explain why and how? please..  Thank you very much in advance..

Please take a look at my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int arr[10] = {7, 7, 3, 2, 9, 8, 5, 1, 7, 9};
    int occur[10] = {NULL};
    int max = 0;
    int most;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            occur[arr[j]]++;
            if(occur[arr[j]] > max)
            {
                max = occur[arr[j]];
                most = arr[j];
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Most frequent: %d\ occurs: %d\n", most, max);

    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the correct answer in "Most Frequent". But the "occurs" is 30, instead of just 3 because 7 occurs 3 times.

Comment: Outer for loop is redundant!

Comment: It is easier to you to compile your code with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) then **use a debugger** (`gdb`) to run your code step by step, than to ask here. Next time, use your debugger

Comment: I'm sorry sir @BasileStarynkevitch. I'm just a beginner and self studying the programming.. I don't even know how to use a debugger. But now I know I have to use it, I'll research for it.. Thank you sir.

Comment: But you should spend some time reading by yourself. the `gdb` debugger has an excellent [user manual](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) containing a tutorial section. You are an adult and need to be able to learn by yourself.

Comment: Why are you incrementing `NULL`? `NULL` is `0` in most cases (although of a different type) but that macro can hold a different number, too, or no number at all.  That your code works (save the unnecessary outer loop causing the x10 bug) is just a happy coincidence.  Please use `int occur[10] = {0};` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ARE multiplying `max` by 10 since you are doing everything 100 times (instead of 10) because of your totally redundant `for i` loop.

Specifically your problem is you are incrementing the values in `occurs` 10 times (instead of once). Since `most` doesn't use the incremented values it doesn't have problem.

Comment: 9 times more than necessary... but yep.

Comment: Thank you very much sir.. That explains it.. So I really don't need the the outer loop. tnx.

Comment: You will need the outer loop cause you're finding the most frequent number and how many times it occurred.

Comment: @suguspnk  the counting can be done in one loop, then getting max value in a second, non-nested loop..

Comment: Happy to delete my answer if someone shows test data where OP's algorithm (one loop version) doesn't work  - sticking with the constraint that all the numbers have to be 0-9 inclusive. It looks right to me, but I've just done it quickly in my head, so I could be wrong...

Comment: @MichaëlRoy How? Let's say you just need to use 1 array which hold the numbers without using another array, how will you get the most frequent number and how many times it occurred? What if there's a number greater than 9 inside the array?

Comment: @suguspnk check my second "answer"

Comment: Haha, yup. Wasn't able to read the edit while typing a reply. :)

Answer (score 2):

It becomes 30 because there is an outer loop which executes 10 times.
I'm guessing that you want to get the most frequent number in the array and how many times it occurred that's why you have an outer loop. This will not work if you have a number in your array that is greater than 9 which will result in index out of bounds problem in occur array. You should change your implementation to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int arr[10] = {7, 7, 3, 2, 9, 8, 5, 1, 7, 9};
    int max = 0;
    int most;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        int tmp = arr[i], count = 0;
        // if the current number is the current max number then skip
        if(tmp == max)
           continue;
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            // increment count if number in index j is equal to tmp number
            count += arr[j] == tmp ? 1 : 0;
        }
        // [this condition will depend on the requirement.]
        // replace max and most if the count of tmp number is greater than your 
        // current max
        if(count > max){
            max = count;
            most = tmp;
        }
    }
    printf("Most frequent: %d\ occurs: %d\n", most, max);

    return 0;
}
```

This is not tested so if there are any problems, please feel free to edit.

Comment: The fact that the inner loop makes no reference to `i` is a hint that it is not in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

The faster, O(2n-1) complexity solution

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int arr[10] = {7, 7, 3, 2, 9, 8, 5, 1, 7, 9};
    int occur[10] = {NULL};
    int max = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
       ++occur[arr[i]];

    for (int i = 1; i < 10; ++i)
       if (occur[i] > occur[max])
         max = i;

    printf("Most frequent: %d\ occurs: %d\n", max, occur[max]);

    return 0;
}
```

Yet faster, in O(n)...  I had a feeling that..

```
int main(){

    int arr[10] = {7, 7, 3, 2, 9, 8, 5, 1, 7, 9};
    int occur[10] = {NULL};
    int max = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
       if (++occur[arr[i]] > occur[max])
          max = arr[i];

    printf("Most frequent: %d\ occurs: %d\n", max, occur[max]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I will not argue that your O(n^2) operations algorithm is not the ideal way to do the task.

But moving one line of code will fix your code.

Your loop:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
        {
            occur[arr[j]]++;
```

Fix:

```
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
  {
      occur[arr[i]]++;
      for(int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
      {
```

I'll let you figure out how you can do this in O(2n) operations or less...